# Need to Authenticate the Users using Twitter, Google, Facebook Apis through oauth plugin?

Tags: oauth, yii, authentication

First i briefly want to know how you can use oauth works. What we need to pass in this plugin and what this plugin will return. Do we have to customize the plugin for different php frameworks. I have seen that their is a different extension of oauth for different framework, why is that?

I need to authenticate the users using social networks in yii framework and I have integrated eouath extension of yii to use oauth and have made an action to use access the ads service of google user like this

public function actionGoogleAds() {

```
    Yii::import('ext.eoauth.*');

    $ui = new EOAuthUserIdentity(
            array(
                //Set the "scope" to the service you want to use
                    'scope'=>'https://sandbox.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/',
                    'provider'=>array(
                            'request'=>'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
                            'authorize'=>'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
                            'access'=>'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
                    )
            )
    );

    if ($ui->authenticate()) {
        $user=Yii::app()->user;
        $user->login($ui);
        $this->redirect($user->returnUrl);
    }
    else throw new CHttpException(401, $ui->error);

}
```

If I want to use other services like linkedin, facebook, twitter just to sign up the user should I just change the scope and parameters or also have to make some changes elsewhere. How do I store user information in my own database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple case you may use the table "*identities*" with fields "*external_id*" and "*provider*". Every OAuth provider must give unique user identificator (uqiue only for that provider). To make it unique on your site you may use pair with provider predefined name (constant). And any other additional fields (if a provider gives it).

In the same table you should store identity data of internal authorization, with provider name 'custom' (for ex.). To store password and other data use a separate table, and PK from this table would be your "*external_id*". Universal scheme.

And PHP, something like this:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    protected $extUserID;

    public function __construct($extUserID)
    {
            $this->extUserID = $extUserID;
    }
  ...
    public function authenticate()
    {
      ...
      //After search $this->extUserID as PK in users table (built-in authorization)
      ...
      $identity = Identities::model()->findByAttributes(array(
            'ext_id' => $this->extUserID,
            'service' => 'forum',
         ));
      if(!count($identity))
      {
            $identity = new Identities;
            $identity->ext_id = $this->extUserID;
            $identity->service = 'forum';
            $identity->username = $userData['username'];
            $identity->save();
      }
      $this->setState('id', $identity->id);
      ...
    }
}
```